# Soldering a VGA cable - number of wires doesn't match

Tags: soldering, vga

I decided to open up a VGA cable which started to produce only red / blue / green colored image. I thought that inside I will find something like shown on  this scheme:

[image]

Instead I found that my VGA cable is a more complex one. Allso the wire colors do not mach with the ones in the scheme above:

[image]

It has 11 wires instead of just 6. My cable has yellow and cyan cables for V-sync and H-sync but then there are these colours (white, gray, brown, black, dark red and bright red) which I don't know where to solder. I need an advice.

Comment: Can't you open the other connector, or use a multimeter to check which wire is connected to which pin?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The other side of this quite long cable is plugged onto a projector on the ceiling. Is it possible that all unknown wires are GND?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector

Comment: Where is the old connector? Can you open it up to check the wiring?

Comment: WIRE COLOR IS NEVER A GOOD INDICATOR OF SIGNAL PURPOSE. You need access to the connector to find out which is what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have 14 wires if you count the ground return for each colour, it may use one of those on pin 5 (GND) as in your diagram to complete the set of 15. The other pins are often used for communications. For example from [VGA connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector) on Wikipedia some of the ones your diagram showns as not connected are:

- Pin 4 - ID2/RES - formerly Monitor ID bit 2, reserved since E-DDC
- Pin 9 - KEY/PWR - formerly key, now +5V DC
- Pin 11 - ID0/RES - formerly Monitor ID bit 0, reserved since E-DDC
- Pin 12 - ID1/SDA - formerly Monitor ID bit 1, I²C data since DDC2
- Pin 15 - ID3/SCL - formerly Monitor ID bit 3, I²C clock since DDC2

The reference to DDC refers to the [Display Data Channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel) that the host can use to query the monitor for its capabilities such as supported resolutions and refresh frequencies. So while I believe in many cases they could be left disconnected with the loss of that functionality they won't all be additional ground signals as you mentioned in a comment.

If you're feeling experimental (and there are no guarantees this won't cause damage) because I'm not sure if the colours are 100% standard I'd try the following:

- Connect the RGB center wires to pins 1/2/3 with the shields going to pins 6/7/8 respectively.
- Short pin 8 to pin 5 to get the additional ground.
- Connect the other wires as per your diagram leaving unknown ones disconnected

Now see if you can get an image on the projector by forcing a resolution you know that it supports because you won't have the DDC channel. If that works OK and it's not a problem leave it at that. Otherwise you could probably identify the remaining pins by measuring between ground and the DDC2 pins 12 / 15 using a scope during initial negotiation to check for the square clock versus data. The 5V to go to pin 9 should be easy enough to spot and is presumably present the whole time.

Answer (score 3):

Nearly all modern PC that have a VGA connector use the same 15 pin VGA connector that the original IBM VGA card used.

There are at least four versions of the VGA connector, which are the three-row [15 pin DE-15](http://pinouts.ru/connector/15_pin_highdensity_D-SUB_female_connector.shtml) (also called mini sub D15) in [original](http://pinouts.ru/Video/VGA15_pinout.shtml#old_vga) and DDC2 pinouts, a less featureful and far less common [9-pin VGA](http://pinouts.ru/Video/VGA9_pinout.shtml), and a [Mini-VGA](http://pinoutsguide.com/Video/mini_vga_connector_pinout.shtml) used for laptops. The image and below table are the newer 15-pin VGA VESA DDC2 connector pinout.

[image]

Comment: Nearly all modern PC graphics cards do not have a VGA connector at all.

Comment: @PeteKirkham - Nearly all modern computers who has the connector has that type of VGA.

Comment: If that's what you meant, correct the answer, don't add a comment.